# Gradle cache not being updated on Mac

Tags: android

The gradle cache is not being updated on mac OS. Is there a way I can use the terminal to allow the files to be updated when I run rebuild.

Comment: Sometimes AS project or gradle cache is not updated correctly, and the only thing which works for me is "invalidate & restart"

Comment: that has not working